# ListView on TOP of Ads - Android

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm having troubles showing ads on bottom of a listview, on my main activity the ads works, the only difference there is that I use a viewpager instead of listview.

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:background="#313131"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="MY_ID" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The listview shows on TOP of the ads and of course can't be clicked, but this same layout works with a viewpager.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:background="#313131"
    app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="MY_ID" />

</LinearLayout >
```

When Ad - is loaded, get his height. Then `ListView bottomMargin = adHeight` and `Ad topMargin = (-1)*adHeight`. Try it.

Comment: The problem is that the banner height is dinamic, depending on the screen size and orientation.

Comment: @Shixons, okay, just refresh LayoutParams of ListView, when banner loaded, and leave your code unchanged. (For refreshing i mean set new LP with Width=match_parent, Height = wrap_content). It should be work.

Comment: That doesn't work, the listview always shows on top of the ads.

Comment: Doesn't work :(, if I set just to test, the layout_height of the listview to 50dp, the listview still fills all the screen and shows on top of the ads.

The only way I fix this is set the view on the fragment, but if I do that I can't use setemptytext() and the fragment doesn't shows a spinner while loading the list.

Comment: You were careful to check my answer? I changed RelativeLay to Linear with vertical orientation. In Me test project - all work fine. And also check AdHeight value, when Ad loaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27826/discussion-between-jimpanzer-and-shixons)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I finally did it in another way, the problem was android.R.id.content I just changed that for a LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Final layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        android:background="#313131"
        app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="MY_ID" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And then replaced:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
```

With:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.listview, list).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
   />

<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#313131"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    ads="SMART_BANNER"
    ads="MY_ID" />
```

NB This is a layout question. It has nothing to do with Admob. If you are using a LinearLayout then just set layout_height="wrap+content" and layout_gravity="1" for the item that you want to expand to consume the unused space. In this case your ListView.

Your problem was really the layout_height="match_parent"

NB I also removed the unnecessary renaming of the ads namespace.

Comment: android:layout_gravity="1" will not work on listView.

Comment: Sorry, I meant layout_weight not layout_gravity. Have adjusted answer.